# How to exit a program with mixed C/C++ cleanly

Tags: c++, c

I'm interfacing a C program (`main()` is in C) with C++. At some points in my code I want to stop execution of the program. Now I'd like to know, how can I do this cleanly?

At the moment I call `std::terminate()` but more out of a lack of better ideas. The main thing that bugs me isn't even that I'm not freeing the memory (because it's freed anyway on program termination, right?) but that the MSVS Just-in-time Debugger pops up and I get an ugly error message about terminating the runtime in an unusual way.

EDIT: As this has caused confusion: Returning from `main()` with `return 0` is not possible in this case.

Comment: What's wrong with `exit(0)` ?

Comment: AFAIK std::terminate is used to indicate an unusual termination (for example when an uncaught exception reaches top-level). This might trigger the debugger.

Comment: The clean way would be to correctly handle the control flow and exit in a standard way (releasing handles, objects, joining threads and so on). `exit(0)`is an ugly alternative

Comment: Something wrong with just falling out of `main()` and returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` like the rest of the known universe?

Comment: Yeah, why aren't you returning from `main` like you're supposed to?

Comment: @Bruce The Recommendation from Microsoft Developer "The Old New Thing"  recommends not releasing handles, allocated memory, or objects due to paying the penalty of causing the page to be requested from swap space  just simply to release it.

Comment: I can't return from main() normally because the underlying C program (on which I have zero influence) will never stop executing, even if it gets an error code. It will just print an error message and go on.

Comment: @fewu if simply returning from main isn't an option, don't you think that should be mentioned *in the question*? Give people the information they need in order to answer your question.

Comment: I thought i implicated that when saying "at some points in the code" but didn't think of people wanting to improve the design of my program ;). Edited the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you concern about cleaning up and invoking destuctors then

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // or EXIT_FAILURE
```

is the best choice between [`exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), [`terminate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate) and [`abort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort).

- Function `exit` calls descructors and cleans up the automatic storage objects (The object which declared in the global scope). It also calls the functions passed to `atexit`.
- Function `abort` is useful for abnormal exits and will not clean up anything. It doesn't call the functions passed to `atexit`.
- Function `terminate` does not exist in C. It's useful when you have an exception and you can't handle it but finishing the program.

Comment: exit doesn't call all destructors

Comment: @user1233963: [_"destructors of objects with static storage duration are called in reverse order of completion of their constructors or the completion of their dynamic initialization_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit)

Comment: @user1233963: The object where declared in the global scope. http://ideone.com/Mtm7LQ -- I've mentioned it in the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

`main` function is where it starts, `main` function is where it should end usually. If you use `return 0;` it indicates succesful exit.

```
int main(void) {
    //init
    //do stuff
    //deinit
    return 0; // bye bye
}
```

You could also use `exit(0);`, but if your exit points are scattered all over the place it makes things harder to debug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make `main()` return 0. Using exit(0) worked, though. Always thought that was kind of a C-ish way to end programs.

Comment: @fewu Make sure your return type for `main` is `int`.